# Qt: Multiple windows in a parent/child chain, parent does not close children?

Tags: windows, qt, parent

I am trying to create multiple windows in a chain: window 1 is the parent of window 2, window 2 is the parent of window 3, etc.  When I close one window, I would like all its children to close as well.  Currently, if I close the top level window, all others close, as hoped, but closing, for example, window 2, only closes window 2, not window 3, etc.  How should I be doing this?  Thanks for your help!

main_window.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Open 1", this);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_button_clicked()));
}

void MainWindow::on_button_clicked() {
    window1 *w = new window1(this);
    w->show();
}
```

window1.cpp

```
window1::window1(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window); // in order to have a free-standing window

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Open 2", this);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_button_clicked()));
}

void window1::on_button_clicked() {
    window2 *w = new window2(this);
    w->show();
}
```

window2.cpp

```
window2::window2(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);

    QLabel* label = new QLabel("Window 2", this);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default QApplication quits when the last primary window (window with no parent) is closed (see [QApplication::lastWindowClosed signal](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qapplication.html#lastWindowClosed)),
that is why closing your MainWindow closes everything.

Closing a widget doesn't delete it, unless the attribute Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose is set (see [QWidget::close()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#close)). If you just want your windows to be closed, I think you have to reimplement closeEvent() to call close() on the children.

But if you want to delete them when closed, then set the attribute Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose. The children are automatically deleted when the parent is deleted.

Comment: That did the trick!  Adding "w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);" in mainwindow.cpp above worked.  Glad I didn't have to reimplement the closeEvent.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know that the widget is not deleted on close by default. This is helpful. Somehow, setting attribute of window to WA_DeleteOnClose for my PySide window solved a segmentation fault problem. Now I just  need to figure out why...

Answer (score 3):

You can overload [closeEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) in every widget that's supposed to have children. Then, either keep a list of your widgets to close in [closeEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent), or just call there deleteLater, which would delete both widget in question and its children.

Comment: I would recommend not keeping track of the children because you can simply find the QMainWindow children in closeEvent. (of course, this is only true unless there are children that you would NOT like to close... whyever this might make sense)

Answer (score 2):

Leiaz has already pointed out why the child-mainWindows' closeEvent(.) is not called. If you need to overload closeEvent(.) of the parent mainWindow to call closeEvent at each child because you do something in there (like storing window settings), you can insert this snippet:

```
auto childList = findChildren<QMainWindow*>();
for (auto child : childList)
{
    child->close();
}
```

Note that the children's QMainWindow children will be called, as well, so there is no need to overload the child-mainWindows' closeEvent, too. In case that you want to only close QMainWindows that are direct children, use:

```
auto childList = findChildren<QMainWindow*>(QString(), Qt::FindDirectChildOnly);
for (auto child : childList)
{
    child->close();
}
```